# How to customise bibliography style with ArsClassica?

Tags: bibliographies

I have to start by saying that I am a newbie to LaTeX.

I chose the `ArsClassica` style for my master thesis, so I downloaded the LaTeX file of the `ArsClassica` guide from [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/arsclassica?lang=en) and went on using this document structure without problems.
`ArsClassica` uses the bibliography style philosophy-modern, but I would like to have something like numeric or ieee, but every time I try to modify it I get an error in the file `biblatex2.sty` at the command `\blx@processoptions`.
How can I solve this?

edit:
The example file loads:
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,hyperref,square,natbib]{biblatex}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can see nowhere in `arsclassica.sty` that it forces use of `biblatex`. Can you show a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @egreg: The example file `arsclassica.tex` loads `\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,hyperref,square,natbib]{biblatex}`.

Comment: Remove also the square option in the biblatex options. It is specific to philosophy-modern.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's sufficient to remove that and substitute with `\usepackage{natbib}`, choosing an appropriate bib style. There's nothing in `arsclassica` that depends on `biblatex`.

Comment: @egreg: I would never replace biblatex by natbib unless  forced. A numeric style is the default with biblatex, and for ieee there is also a biblatex style.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That depends on the document author's preferences. I added the hint to my answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The square option was exactly what was causing the problem. I would flag it as accepted answer if it weren't a comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove  the `square` option in the biblatex options. It is specific to the style `philosophy-modern`.

You could have found the source for error quite easily simply by looking at the log-file. It tells you that it doesn't like `square`:

```
! Package keyval Error: square undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10997 \blx@processoptions
```

Answer (score 1):

The example file bundled with `arsclassica` is

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage,fleqn,%
               headinclude,,footinclude,BCOR5mm,%
               numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty,%
               tablecaptionabove]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[italian,american]{babel}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,hyperref,square,natbib]{biblatex}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,subfig,beramono,eulermath,pdfspacing,listings]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\input{arsclassica-settings}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
%******************************************************************
% Frontmatter
%******************************************************************
\input{FrontBackMatter/Titlepage}
\input{FrontBackMatter/Titleback}
\clearpage
\input{FrontBackMatter/Abstract+Sommario}
\input{FrontBackMatter/Acknowledgements}
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\clearpage
\input{FrontBackMatter/Contents}
\cleardoublepage
%******************************************************************
% Mainmatter
%******************************************************************
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{Chapters/Fundamentals}
\input{Chapters/Code}
% *****************************************************************
% Backmatter
%******************************************************************
\clearpage
\input{FrontBackMatter/Bibliography}
\clearpage
\input{FrontBackMatter/Index}
\end{document}
```

There is no need to load *all* these packages; they're loaded here just for building the example document.

You just need

```
\documentclass[
  10pt,
  a4paper,
  twoside,
  openright,
  titlepage,
  fleqn,
  headinclude,
  footinclude,
  BCOR5mm,
  numbers=noenddot,
  cleardoublepage=empty,
  tablecaptionabove,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % or whatever encoding
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % or whatever language

\usepackage[
  eulerchapternumbers,
  %subfig,% uncomment if you load subfig
  beramono,
  eulermath,
  pdfspacing,
  %listings,% uncomment if you load listings
]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
```

In particular you're free to use the bibliography management you like, for example

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

There is also no need to organize the directories in the exact way Lorenzo Pantieri likes. Use your preferred method.

Note that an IEEE compliant style is available also for `biblatex`: do

```
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
```

for it (without calling `natbib` and `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`, of course).